# How can I check if my color value is equal to Null

Tags: c#, wpf, color-picker

I need help trying to find if the selected color is null.

Because if I do not choose a color, I get an error

This is the code that I get the error with:

```
private void btnreturn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int gettext;
    int.TryParse(txtcount.Text, out gettext);

    Color Colorpicker; 

    //this is where I am getting my error and I need to 
    //check to see if the selected colour is not null before taking its value
    Colorpicker = (Color)colorpicker.SelectedColor;

    MainWindow win2 = new MainWindow(gettext, Colorpicker);
    win2.Show();
    Close();
}
```

Comment: You mean like "Colorpicker == null"?

Comment: You need to create a `new ColorPicker(...)`. `Color`cannot be null, but `ColorPicker` can.

Comment: This is done with a simple google search. You should research before asking questions.

Comment: I did do some research before asking but everything i found is advanced and in the end did not fix my problem

Comment: @NathanCooley It allways helps to provide the full error when asking questions. Your code is wrong in many ways so this is not easily answered. I assume you want to display a ColorPicker when you click a button?

Comment: @CSharpie I am sorry this is my first time asking a question on this site. and that is not my full code. it is just the section that has the error. the error that shows is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Nullable object must have a value."

Comment: @NathanCooley As people have already suggested, it's probably better to include more of your code and the error you're getting. We can't see what `colorpicker` is, and where it's being initialized. It seems that might be causing the issue, as it could be `null`. But, in all honesty, it's hard to tell with the question the way it currently is. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @NathanCooley - If you *do* select a colour, you don't get an error, right?

Comment: @GeoffJames that is correct. if i do select a color it runs properly.

Comment: @NathanCooley - well, your check might need to be instead based on the `colorpicker.SelectedColor` <- the `SelectedColor` is probably null, and causing your error. Check it (like the other suggestions in answers) by doing `if (colorpicker.SelectedColor != null) { ... // do something } else { ... // something else }`

Comment: @NathanCooley - might I also suggest that you name your variables a little more appropriately..?

Comment: @GeoffJames i have tried these suggestions. But i can not get it to run an if statement inside of the code. it keeps skipping the "if" and giving the error again about .Selectedcolor being null

Comment: @NathanCooley - I've added an example in my answer below. Are you **sure** that your `colorpicker` object is not the issue? Also - another question: Are you using C#6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when you don't select a color from the `colorpicker`, that the `colorpicker.SelectedColor` is `null`, and causing your error.

---

You can check for this in your code, like so:

```
private void btnreturn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int gettext;
    int.TryParse(txtcount.Text, out gettext);

    Color Colorpicker; 

    // Check if the SelectedColor is not null, and do stuff with it
    if (colorpicker.SelectedColor != null)
    {
        Colorpicker = (Color)colorpicker.SelectedColor;

        MainWindow win2 = new MainWindow(gettext, Colorpicker);
        win2.Show();
        Close();
    }
    else
    {
        // You didn't select a color... do something else
    }
}
```

**Side-note:** if you are using C#6, and you want to be sure that your `colorpicker` object is not `null`, in your `if` check - you can use `colorpicker?.SelectedColor` also. Note the use of the `?` which checks that the underlying object is not null before checking its property.

---

I would also suggest naming your variables a little more clearly and meaningfully...

For example, your `Color Colorpicker;` variable declaration. Would it not be better suited to `Color selectedColor;`?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Any explanation on the downvote, guys? I'd love to improve my post if possible :)

Comment: Thank you. this did help alot i am sorry for the lack of information on my code. i am new on this site and was not sure exactly what was expected in a post

Comment: No worries @NathanCooley! Glad it helped. I've also added a note about C#6 checks for null - might not be completely applicable to this scenario, but it could help in future. Shame about the downvote from whomever with no explanation, though... Happy coding! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
If (Colorpicker != null)
{
   //Do code
}
else
{

}
```

This checks whether 'Colorpicker' is not equal to null.

Couldn't post a comment, so if this is not what you need I apologise c:

Comment: Sorry, @Hypyx, and I know that your answer should probably be more of a comment (and I get that you can't post them, yet) - but there's so many problems with the OP's code as it is. It's probably best to get more of an idea of the underlying problem, rather than just throwing in a `null` check as a suggestion.

Comment: Ah, I can comment here gg. Is the lowercase 'colorpicker' a Telerik RadColorPicker?

Answer (score -1):

would something like this work? check it for null before trying to add it. or initialize the variable with a different value.

```
   private void btnreturn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int gettext;
    int.TryParse(txtcount.Text, out gettext);




 Color Colorpicker; 

        //this is where i am getting my error and i need to 
       //check to see if the selected colour is not null before taking it's value
    if(colorpicker.SelectedColor != null){
        Colorpicker = (Color)colorpicker.SelectedColor;
    MainWindow win2 = new MainWindow(gettext, Colorpicker);
    win2.Show();
    Close();
    } else {
         //do something else
    }

}
```

Edit: as per @Geoff James the cast to (color) is removed

Comment: Alex, throwing in a `null` check is *not* going to solve the issue. The code won't compile.

Comment: i have tried to run this in my code but it will not even run the if statement because it still says the error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Nullable object must have a value."

Comment: @Geoff James you say that yet you posted the same code I did.

Comment: @AlexRohr - no - I didn't post the *same* code. Your `if` check tries to cast the `colorpicker.SelectedColor` to a `Color` in the `if ()` statement, which would still throw an exception if it is null. Read mine a bit more *carefully*...

Comment: @NathanCooley - It's because Alex's suggestion is trying to cast the `colorpicker.SelectedColor` to a `Color` **before** checking if it is null. You need to check if the `SelectedColor` is null *before* casting it - see my answer